# What is the EOL for 5.33-ESR

Tags: esr

I need to know when the EOL of 5.33-ESR is. I'm a subscriber and I checked [here](https://lab.civicrm.org/esr/core/-/releases) and other places but couldn't find it.

Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://civicrm.org/esr#faqs:

> For how long is each version of ESR supported?
>
> At present, each version of ESR will receive 6 months of support. The CiviCRM Core Team may extend the release to a full 12 months of support, depending on the financial viability of maintaining this version of CiviCRM.

So I calculate:

- Current: 5.36
- May: 5.37
- June: 5.38
- July: 5.39 => next ESR

Answer (score 2):

See also https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/release/-/blob/master/README.md with tentative ESR dates.